# Is there any alternative for the code TextFieldName.setText("") in java to clear the text in a textfield?

Tags: java, android

Is there any alternative for the code `TextFieldName.setText("")` in java to clear the text in a textfield?

Comment: `textInputLayout.getEditText().getText().clear();  //TextInputLayout.`
`editText.getText().clear(); //EditText`
`textView.setText("");  //TextView`

Answer (score 0):

in JAVA `TextFieldName.setText(null) ;`
in Kotlin `TextFieldName.clearText();`

Answer (score 0):

You can clear by using following code: -

```
editTextName.getText().clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

if its an EditText you can clear by using

```
TextFieldName.getText().clear();
```

if its a TextView the above method is the right one

```
TextFieldName.setText("");
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Editable` there's a clear method

```
/**
 * Convenience for replace(0, length(), "", 0, 0).
 * Note that this clears the text, not the spans;
 * use {@link #clearSpans} if you need that.
 * @see #replace(int, int, CharSequence, int, int)
 */
public void clear();
```

So for `Edittext`

```
Edittext.getText().clear();
```